# Best way to Uniquely Pair Array Elements (where elements are primitive types and arrays)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was recently given the following challenge to complete in 30 minutes:

*From a collection of tennis players create unique teams of 2. Once the teams are in place create a list of potential tennis matches between all the teams; with no duplicates matches.*

My answer below works, but due to time constraints I had to brute force it. It appears there's some concept I'm missing. At the very least there's definitely a more efficient way to code it. I'll be tweaking it on my [codepen here](https://codepen.io/ryannmedina/pen/WNRPoaV).

```js
const players = ["Mickey", "Donald", "Goofy", "Minny", "Woody"];

const makeTeams = (players) => {
  let teams = [];
  let i = 0;
  
  players.forEach((player) => {  
    for (let j = i; j < players.length; j++) {
      let team = [player];

      if (player !== players[j]) {
        team.push(players[j]);
        teams.push(team);
      }
    }

    i++;
  });

  return teams;
};

const makeMatches = (teams) => {
  let matches = [];
  let i = 0;

  teams.forEach((team) => {
    for (let j = i; j < teams.length; j++) {
      let match = [team];

      let sameTeam = team[0] === teams[j][0] && team[1] === teams[j][1];
      let samePlayers = team[0] === teams[j][0] || team[1] === teams[j][0] || team[0] === teams[j][1] || team[1] === teams[j][1];

      if (!sameTeam && !samePlayers) {
        match.push(teams[j]);
        matches.push(match);
      }
    }

    i++;
  });

  return matches;
};

// Display Teams
const teams = makeTeams(players);

const teamsList = document.getElementById("teams");

teams.forEach((team) => {
  let el = document.createElement("li");

  el.innerText = team[0] + " and " + team[1];

  teamsList.appendChild(el);
});

// Display Matches
const matches = makeMatches(teams);

const matchList = document.getElementById("matches");

matches.forEach((match) => {
  let el = document.createElement("li");

  let team1 = match[0][0] + " and " + match[0][1];
  let team2 = match[1][0] + " and " + match[1][1];

  el.innerText = team1 + " vs " + team2;

  matchList.appendChild(el);
});
```

```html
<h2>Teams</h2>
<ul id="teams"></ul>

<h2>Matches</h2>
<ul id="matches"></ul>
```

Comment: So your code is working, you are looking for improvement suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, improvement would be good. For instance I know makeTeams and makeMatches could be combined. Also, I feel like I'm missing some CS concept for handling arrays. (maybe not)

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [codereview.se]. However be sure to take their [tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and read their [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page before posting.

Comment: Good tip. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

**One more way**

```js
const players = ["Mickey", "Donald", "Goofy", "Minny", "Woody"];

function makeTeam(players) {
  const teams = [];
  const set = new Set();

  players.forEach((p1, i) => {
    players.forEach((p2, j) => {
      if (i !== j && !set.has(`${p2}|${p1}`)) {
        set.add(`${p1}|${p2}`);
        teams.push([p1, p2]);
      }
    });
  });

  return [teams, set];
}

function createMatches(teams) {
  const matches = [];
  const matchesSet = new Set();

  teams.forEach((t1) => {
    teams.forEach((t2) => {
      const uniqueTeams = new Set([...t1, ...t2]);
      const [a, b] = t1;
      const [c, d] = t2;
      const set = `${a}|${b}||${c}|${d}`;
      if (uniqueTeams.size === 4 && !matchesSet.has(`${c}|${d}||${a}|${b}`)) {
        matchesSet.add(set);
        matches.push([t1, t2]);
      }
    });
  });
  return matches;
}

const [teams, set] = makeTeam(players);
const matches = createMatches(teams);
console.log(`Total matches: ${matches.length}`);
matches.forEach((m) => {
  const [a, b] = m;
  console.log(`${a.join(" and ")} vs ${b.join(" and ")}`);
});
```

Comment: Using a set is a good idea! Especially since you don't have to worry about deduping. Thanks!